# React onChange is not working. Can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I have a weird problem with this code. I think everything is correct, and I compared it with other similar codes and I can't find the issue.

The thing is that the `onChange` is not writing on input on my React Component. But, if I change the name of the useState initial value, so it does not match my input, it works, because it has no relation with the initial object.

Here is my code:

```
 import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const NuevoProyecto = () => {
  //State para proyecto

  const [proyecto, guardarProyecto] = useState({
    nombre: "",
  });

  //extraer nombre de proyecto

  const { nombre } = proyecto;

  //Lee contenidos del Input
  const onChangeProyecto = (e) => {
    guardarProyecto({
      ...proyecto,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  //Cuando el user envia un proyecto
  const onSubmitProyecto = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Validar el proyecto

    //agregar al state

    //reiniciar el form
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-block btn-primario">
        Nuevo Proyecto
      </button>

      <form className="formulario-nuevo-proyecto" onSubmit={onSubmitProyecto}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="input-text"
          placeholder="Nombre Proyecto"
          nombre="nombre"
          value={nombre}
          onChange={onChangeProyecto}
        />

        <input
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primario btn-block"
          value="Agregar Proyecto"
        />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default NuevoProyecto;
```

Here is the picture of the Components Dev Tool with the input:

[image]

Comment: Typo in the name input, `nombre="nombre"` should be `name="nombre"`. The change handler is accessing the `name` attribute of the input change event. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input
   type="text"
   className="input-text"
   placeholder="Nombre Proyecto"
   name="nombre"
   value={nombre}
   onChange={onChangeProyecto}
/>
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Comment: Thanks Guys. OMG! Those things that are so easy that sometimes you cannot see. One rule: develop in English. Lol

Answer (score 0):

while initalising the state using the useState function , you have mentioned a property nombre: "" as a string and afterwards you are initializing the state with the same property... this code is so verbose.

you are writting a redundant code. you dont have initialize the state with some property . properties can be added later as well using the spread operator as you have done in the later half of the code.

const [proyecto, guardarProyecto] = useState({

});

//remove this line. and edit the first line. rest everything looks fine.
//const { nombre } = proyecto;